# How to rewrite a subdomain with suffix at apache's .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've created an alias for subdomain "api" on my server using this following code on `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/ /assets/api/app/index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

And it's working fine through this following url:

```
https://api.mysite.com/assets/api/app
```

But I need want to add a suffix `/app/` to the address to rewrite `api.mysite.com/app/` to `/assets/api/app/index.php`

After that I will user others suffixes to rewrite for example:

Example 01 (suffix app):

- Origin: `api.mysite.com/app/carts`
- Destination: `/assets/api/images/index.php`

to receive only carts

Example 02 (suffix images):

- Origin: `api.mysite.com/images/banner/21`
- Destination: `/assets/api/images/index.php`

to receive only `banner/21`

Example 03 (suffix lib):

- Origin: `api.mysite.com/lib/lib.js`
- Destination: `/assets/api/libs/index.php`

to receive only `carousel/21`

All the context will be used in my restful api.

```
api.mysite.com/app/carts
```

My restful API is getting the path `app/carts` but I want to pass only `/carts` to `index.php`.

Server's root is:

```
/home/storage/c/bc/69/mysite
```

I want that the server ignores those following suffixes: app, images e lib. Someone know how to do it?

[image: Error routing]

Ps.: I've my .htaccess working as a charm while accessed directly by [www.mysite.com/asssets/api/app/carts](http://www.mysite.com/asssets/api/app/carts) and this is the code for .htaccess stored in /home/storage/c/bc/69/mysite/assets/api:

> RewriteRule ^(^app/){1} /assets/api/app/index.php [NC,QSA]

Comment: What is the URL that you want to show in browser and what should it be rewritten to in backend?

Comment: @anubhava I want to show https://api.mysite.com/app/carts and rewrite to /assets/api/app/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to handle this rewrite:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/ /assets/api/app/index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: It's rewriting api.mysite.com/app/carts to /app/carts ... But I want to rewrite only to /carts ... It's passing sufix /app/ ... I want to remove it

Comment: ok try my updated answer. Make sure this htaccess is in site root of api subdomain

Comment: It remains showing error routing... because It's tryting to route to /app/carts and the right route is just /carts

Comment: I think the problem is because It's rewriting api.mysite.com and It should to be rewriting api.bilhetix.com/app .... Because it needs to ignore "app" sufix

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question. My rule only rewrite `api.bilhetix.com/app/*`

Comment: Ok I had update my question... Please replace website's name for "mysite". Thanks

Comment: `My Api restfull is getting the path app/carts but I want to pass only /carts to index.php` - You have to use either a `$_GET` variable or `PATH_INFO` as `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` will still be same after these rewrites.

Comment: I'm using symfony's silex framework and this workound will not be clean for my application.. Because I need to rewrite the path to the right directory ... Every suffix has its own api...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235458/discussion-between-vinoli-and-anubhava).